# Combine Route Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Rails so bear with me.

I have a post resource and a comment resource. I can access the following routes:

```
domain.com/post/new
```

Or

```
domain.com/post/2
```

Or

```
domain.com/post/2/edit
```

I can access the exact same routes for comments too.

The question is, how can I make a route for adding a comment to a post directly? Like such:

```
domain.com/post/2/comment/new
```

This route should just render the existing comment form but already have the post ID. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to read up on has_many associations, nested routes and accepts_nested_attributes_for. Your route will be

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```